# Nullpointer exception Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

```
[qtask-worker-15] ERROR qi.qtask.impl.consumer - Caught an error while processing  8a10fa31-28dc-47db-be15-b765d3bc877b :
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:597) ~[spring-orm-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at qi.qtask.compat$execute_single_task.invoke(compat.clj:116) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at qi.qtask.compat$execute_task.invoke(compat.clj:405) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at qi.qtask.exec$eval1000.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:0) ~[na:na]
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6666) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2927) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at qi.qtask.impl.consumer$fn__4074$fn__4080.invoke(consumer.clj:68) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at qi.qtask.impl.consumer$exec_task.invoke(consumer.clj:171) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at qi.qtask.impl.concurrent$wrap_pause_if_async$fn__3463.invoke(concurrent.clj:206) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at io.pedestal.service.impl.interceptor$try_f.invoke(interceptor.clj:33) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at io.pedestal.service.impl.interceptor$enter_all_with_binding.invoke(interceptor.clj:98) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at io.pedestal.service.impl.interceptor$enter_all$fn__251.invoke(interceptor.clj:113) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at io.pedestal.service.impl.interceptor$enter_all.invoke(interceptor.clj:111) ~[qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at io.pedestal.service.impl.interceptor$execute.invoke(interceptor.clj:290) [qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at qi.qtask.impl.consumer$default_threadpool_executor$f__4069.invoke(consumer.clj:52) [qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:na]
        at com.quantumretail.qtask.ResourceAwareThreadPoolExecutor$ResourceLoadAwareCallable.call(ResourceAwareThreadPoolExecutor.java:200) [qtask-clj-7.3.2.3.2.jar:7.3.2.3.2-a2ae0e6-dirty]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_85]
        at com.quantumretail.rcq.predictor.CallableTaskTracker$1.run(CallableTaskTracker.java:54) [rcq-0.3.jar:0.3-${buildNumber}]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_85]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_85]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_85]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:556) ~[spring-orm-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Can some help to solve the error

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What you are trying to do & some code would be helpful...